# VB6 Legacy Code can't "Call Shell"

Tags: shell, windows-7, vb6, legacy, vb6-migration

I am working on some legacy VB6 code and I am having my program break with this message:

[image]

and it then highlights this code:

[image]

I know that the specified locations exist per these screenshots:

[image]
[image]

I am running this Visual Studio 6.0 on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine. How can I make the program see shell?

Comment: Are you sure FileServer & "\public\Drafting" exists?

Comment: You do know that `command.com` is very legacy and old? You should use `%comspec%` or `cmd.exe` or the required command directly if it's an executable.

Comment: In addition to the already posted answers you may also need to be running your process elevated in order to achieve what you want

Answer (score 4):

command.com does not exist on 64 bit windows.

Try using C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe instead. C:\Windows\SysWOW64 is a folder giving you backwards compatibility stuff for 32 bit.

But see the comment below (taken from Euro Micelli).

Really you should use %SYSTEMROOT\System32\cmd.exe instead. First, Windows is not always installed in C:\Windows; you should let the system figure that out. Second, using System32 is always correct for a 32-bit application: when running on Win32, it is the correct folder; when running on Win64, Windows will map %SYSTEMROOT%\System32 to %SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64

Comment: Actually, you should use `%SYSTEMROOT\System32\cmd.exe` instead. First, Windows is not always installed in `C:\Windows`; you should let the system figure that out. Second, using System32 is always correct for a 32-bit application: when running on Win32, it is the correct folder; when running on Win64, Windows will map `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32` to `%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64` for you.

Comment: Indeed Euro Micelli, I'll amend the answer. Sorry, was being a little lazy; Friday after all.

Answer (score 2):

I use vb6 and windows 7.

I've done the same thing as you but I put the dos command in a bat file.

Login.bat

```
NET USE W: \\10.48.10.8\e$
```

Then in the code 
    Shell ("c:\login.bat")

Comment: Note that there is a VERY big difference between DOS and the command line interface to Windows!

Answer (score 1):

The vb command is not correct for the OS that you are running. You need to check that that drive is not already mapped, and remove the command.com /c from the command that you are trying to execute.